# MAP COLLECTION is it possible with Android Apps?

Tags: android

Hi can we implement the Map Collections for android? or is it just the arrays? I'm trying to implement a Yellow Pages app and I was wondering if I could use a map to have names and numbers as keys and values.

Comment: Here's a tutorial. http://bit.ly/TvPlHQ

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can - I suggest you read [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/index.html) about collections in java.
In particular, you have several [map implementations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html), such as HashMap and LinkedHashMap.